# Cannot unload previous swf while loading the new ones

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have made a main navigation page in adobe flash and 3 buttons in it. I have used this code in order to call some external swf's according to the button pressed. Problem is that when i press the button to load one swf i want the previous one to be unloaded. How can i do that i have tried everything

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();        
var myLoaderMain:URLRequest = new URLRequest("main1.swf");
var myLoaderQuiz:URLRequest = new URLRequest("quiz.swf");
var myLoaderAnimation:URLRequest = new URLRequest("athens_animation.swf");
var myLoaderVideo:URLRequest = new URLRequest("videogallery.swf");


videogallerybtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoFunc);

function videoFunc(curEvt:MouseEvent) {
myLoader.load(myLoaderVideo);
addChild(myLoader); 
 }

 Quizbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quizFunc);
 function quizFunc(curEvt:MouseEvent) {
myLoader.load(myLoaderQuiz);
addChild(myLoader);

 }

 Animationbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AnimationFunc);

 function AnimationFunc(curEvt:MouseEvent) {
myLoader.load(myLoaderAnimation);
addChild(myLoader);
 }
```

Comment: you need to unload the loader, remove child

Answer (score 0):

Have two event listeners for each button, the first Mouse_Down to unload the loader and MOUSE_UP to load the loader .

```
    videogallerybtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
    videogallerybtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUP);

     function MouseDown(curEvt:MouseEvent) {
     trace("mouseDown so unload, remove");
     }

     function MouseUP(curEvt:MouseEvent) {
     trace("mouseUP so load something and add it");
     }
```

Hopefully you get the principle.